# How to insert an external JAR to the "Plug-in Dependencies" in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use eclipse Luna for Java. I'm trying to add an external JAR to the "Plug-in Dependencies". I press `Project -> Properties -> Java build path -> Add external JAR's` and choose it. But the problem is, it does not insert it into the "Plug-in Dependencies" as shown in the following image (it creates a new folder "Referenced Libraries")

[image]

Rather, I want it to be:

[image]

What should I do?
I tried to choose the "Plug-in Dependencies" library and click edit but it says

[image]

**EDIT**: the reason I want to do it is that I have the following situation:

[image]

I get an error in the MAINFEST.MF file:

[image]

The error: `Bundle 'org.apache.commons.cli' cannot be resolved`.
My old Eclipse worked with the way I mentioned before (The jar file is in the "Plug-in Dependencies" library). Trying to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Although there is a way to access external jars it is **extremely** tricky to use especially in a portable way. Plug-ins should normally only access code in plug-ins. Include the jar in a plug-in.

Comment: @greg-449 Hi Greg, thanks for the fast reply. I edit the post to explain the reason.

Comment: Entries in the MANIFEST.MF Bundle-Classpath normally only refer to other plug-ins not plain jars. It looks like you used to have an org.apache.commons.cli plugin and no longer do. As I said using an external jar will cause endless problems. Either find the plugin or create your own containing the jar.